# How to normalize resize event in Opera?

Tags: javascript, resize, opera

Resize event in Opera works like `onresizeend` (http://help.dottoro.com/ljscshjn.php). How to normalize it like in other browsers?

Comment: I've given an answer but it would be useful to have a link to a page showing what you have tried to do, so that I can be sure I've understood the question correctly :)

Answer (score 0):

You mean it only fires when you stop resizing something, rather than several times during a resize? This is an implementation detail, and as far as I know there is no way to subscribe to recurring resize events or "normalize" it. If you need to update something while an element is being resized, you'll have to use timeouts to query the size.

Comment: Yes, I mean this. Even timeouts like any scripts not working during resize!

Comment: hm.. isn't there an operating system setting or something controlling whether to show window contents during a resize? Perhaps it needs to be enabled?

Comment: It has been tested on many computers with Opera on Windows - it's the same

Comment: And if you try to console.log(something) with timeout: after resize moment all not fired timeouts will be fired in one moment.